# why does this loop do one more iteration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There is a list of roles that are stored in a database and there is only one of these in the model. The Entity Framework is used to populate the model but I don't think it is important here.

The code blow seems to be used to iterate over these:

```
foreach (var role in (new Role[1]).Concat(model.Roles))
{
}
```

But to be honest with you I cannot understand for the life of me what this code is doing. All I know is that it is looping twice rather than once. Can anyone clarify what it is doing?

Comment: Why are you doing a `new`? Have you tried doing `var temp = new Role[1]).Concat(model.Roles)` and analysing what `temp` contains? Are you 100% sure `model.Roles` only contains one object?

Comment: @ChrisF It's not my code unfortunately which is why I am asking as I just do not understand what it is doing. Yes there is only one role shown in the database. Yes doing what you suggest is probably a good idea should have thought of that! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `new Role[1]` creates an array containing a single element. That element is `null` unless `Role` is a value type which I assume it isn't. Otherwise it is what you get by calling `new Role()`.

You then concatenate the `null` role with whatever roles are in `model.Roles`. The end result is that you prepend `null` to the collection of roles in `model.Roles`. You then iterate over this new collection.

If `model.Roles` contains the elements

```
{ role1, role2, role3 }
```

your `foreach` loop will iterate

```
{ null, role1, role2, role3 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I can now understand what it is doing. I have no idea why it was programmed like that but he defect is now obvious.

Answer (score 2):

`Concat` concatenates two sequences. It pretty much works like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
{
  foreach(T item in first)
    yield return item;
  foreach(T item in second)
    yield return second;
}
```

`(new Role[1]).Concat(model.Roles)` therefore creates an array of one `Role` (`new Role[1]`), whatever is in `model.Roles` and then returns the sequence of the first followed by the second, that is one default `Role` (null if `Role` is a reference type) and then all of `model.Roles`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will accept Martin's answer as it looks like it was done first but have +1'd you for the great answer

Comment: Always a good approach when two answers seem equally good to you.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Concat creates an iterator over both arrays. so the 2 queries.